# When do I have sufficient evidence to believe that an observed event is an occurrence of a very rare event with similar characteristics?

Tags: probability, evidence, decision-theory

Suppose I am aware of a particular type of event which only occurs every 10,000 years. Call this type of event ‘A’.

Suppose that I now observe an event which has many characteristics that event ‘A’ also has whenever it happens, and no characteristics which suggest that the event was not an occurrence of ‘A’ (i.e. evidence against the event being ‘A’). It seems to me that whether or not I do have sufficient evidence to believe that the event really was an occurrence of ‘A’ will depend on how many characteristics the event shares with ‘A’, and how significant each of those characteristics is, but I am not sure.

Will I have sufficient evidence to believe that the event really was an occurrence of ‘A’ or not? If not, why not, and how will I ever have sufficient evidence to believe that a particular event really is an occurrence of ‘A’?

**Edit:** I am particularly interested in cases where I have some very convincing argument which shows that 'A' occurs every 10,000 years, but I don't know when it last happened.

Comment: If you know that the event occurs only all 10.000 years, then try to find out when it last happened. Example: Recurrence of a periodic comet.

Comment: @JoWehler What if I don't know when it last happened, but I do somehow know its periodicity?

Comment: If you don't know when it happened last: From where do you know that it happened at all, and from where do you know that the event is periodic with period 10.000 years?

Comment: @JoWehler Please see my edit. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you don't know the dates of the last three occurrences at least, how can you possibly know its periodicity? Without that, how can the argument be 'convincing'? This sounds like an "oh it must have been an X. How lucky I am." Please tell us what 10,000 year event you believe to have happened.

Answer (score 1):

## What else could it be?

The question is very vague, and so my answer will be as well. The extent to which you can conclude that you witnessed an event of type A depends on what alternatives are possible; do the characteristics you observed also fit an event of type B, which happens once a year? If so, B seems far more plausible than A.

If the field of study associated with the category of events into which A falls is relatively well-understood, and no events with the characteristics you witnessed are known except for A, then you could make the case that an unknown kind of event is far less likely and conclude you witnessed an event of type A.

Without an alternative to compare this event to, the 10,000 year figure does not really change the consideration; If I observe an event sharing some characteristics with C, which happens every day, but some event D which also has those characteristics happens ten thousand times per day, then C and A seem to be equally unlikely (assuming the existence of a once-a-year B event like I mentioned).

Comment: +1 for pointing out that the question is hopelessly vague.

Answer (score 0):

The question is how do you know whether a thing is an instance of some other type of thing, and the answer is that it depends on the nature of the things and on the threshold of certainty you are prepared to accept. In some cases it will be clear-cut- for example (excusing the obvious pun), you can determine whether a thing is a diamond with one or two decisive tests. That is because diamond has unique properties.

On the other hand, suppose you wanted to establish whether a painting found in an attic was a Rembrandt. A single test might prove it was not- for example, if you could show that the paints used where made of modern pigments, you would know for sure that Rembrandt could not have painted it. Likewise if you carbon dated the canvass, or found it was synthetic etc etc. But if all those clear-cut tests were passed, you have still not proved it was a Rembrandt. So then you rely on less decisive determinations- was the style of the brushwork like Rembrandt's and so on. Even if those tests are passed, you cannot say for sure it is a Rembrandt- it could have been one of his talented apprentices. Then perhaps you dig-up some documents from the records of some auction house which show that the painting seems to match the description of a Rembrandt sold in 1903. Etc etc etc. As you get over each hurdle in the chain of investigation, you exclude more and more uncertainty, but if you cannot eliminate all of it you must decide on a case-by-case basis whether you have eliminated enough, and that depends on what is at stake. The greater the consequences of the decision, the higher should be the threshold of certainty to justify it.